# Laravel PHPUnit Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Util_Configuration' not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I am trying to start testing my Laravel 5.1 app using PHPUnitbut everytime I run phpunit in the cmd line I get the following error:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Util_Configuration' not found in C:\Users\ross\AppData\Local\Temp\PHPCD2E.tmp on line 347

Call Stack:
    0.0001     116952   1. {main}() -:0
    0.0011     266968   2. require_once('C:\Users\ross\AppData\Local\Temp\PHPCD2E.tmp') -:1

C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
```

I have check my settings as far as I understand they are all pretty default as they come with Laravel.
Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening and how I can fix it?
Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you trying to run phpunit?

Comment: Are you using pear? Laravel pulls in phpunit via composer right? Can you not do it that way? From my application root I usually run it by doing `vendor/bin/phpunit` you can of course set up an alias for this.

Comment: The `C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit` path suggests that you installed PHPUnit via PEAR. That mode of installation has not been supported for years and is not possibly anymore since December 31, 2014: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/End-of-Life-for-PEAR-Installation-Method

Comment: My bad I have also tried running it from [C:\xampp\php\phpunit] and it runs but with the same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out running `./vendor/bin/phpunit` works thanks to @kaakym for pointing em in the right direction